# What are all the classes related to Selenium and how are they internally linked (in a hierarchy)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What are all the classes related to Selenium and how are they internally linked (in hierarchical order)?

Answer (score 0):

The key you are looking for is selenium webdriver architecture.

You can found many article on google for same

Example:

https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/selenium-webdriver-architecture/

https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-webdriver

https://chercher.tech/java/index-selenium-webdriver

http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2017/03/03/architecture-of-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

All the classes related to [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and how are they internally linked can be sumarized through the following [diagram](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/images/maven.png):

[image: maven.png]

Answer (score 0):

[low level architecture of selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt9q2.jpg)

This image shows hot interfaces and classes are interlinked in selenium.